# Migrate database through database link

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, windows, oracle-10g, oracle-xe

There's a database called `FOO` in an Oracle XE 10g server that's due to be decommissioned (`old.example.com`). I've been asked to migrate it to some other Oracle XE 11g server (`new.example.com`). Both servers are on the same LAN. I don't know anything about the database (it isn't a project of mine). There isn't a DBA in the room. My random Google searches suggest it's a terribly complicated task. I can use SQL Developer or SQL*Plus.

I've figured out that using [impdp over a network link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/expimp.htm#UPGRD52674) might be a reasonably straightforward method. But docs take most stuff for granted and I can't make it work.

So far:

1. I've assigned `EXP_FULL_DATABASE` to user `FOO` in source server (role `DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE` does not seem to exist in 10g).
2. I've created a temporary user called `tmp_imp` in target server with `CREATE DATABASE LINK` and `DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE` roles.
3. I'm stuck in the *create database link* part. I've logged into `new.example.com` as `tmp_imp` and tried all possible combinations of the [CREATE DATABASE LINK](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5005.htm) statement. They either trigger `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` or are accepted but produce a non-working link (`ORA-39001: invalid argument value`, `ORA-39200: Link name "OLD_FOO" is invalid.`, `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`).

This is one of my attempts:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK OLD_FOO
CONNECT TO FOO IDENTIFIED BY 'pa$$w0rD'
USING '//old.example.com:1521/xe';
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a simpler tool to migrate the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `USING` clause expects a valid TNS entry or alias. Use this:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK OLD_FOO
CONNECT TO FOO IDENTIFIED BY "pa$$w0rD"
USING '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = old.example.com)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))';
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I meant with docs taking stuff for granted. Do you have any idea why I get `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` when I run a verbatin copy of your command? SQL*Plus reports it in the first quote of ´'pa$$w0rD'´, but removing quotes altogether doesn't fix it.

Comment: @Álvaro González You should use double quotes for the password because of the special characters, I edited my answer.